# Copy(Explicit) Initialization vs. Direct(Implicit) Initialization C++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I was reading up upon variable initialization and I came across three different ways to initialize variables: Copy, Direct, and Uniform. 
source: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/2-1-fundamental-variable-definition-initialization-and-assignment/comment-page-1/#comments

My question is what is the difference between using the copy vs direct initialization for fundamental types?

The website states, "(Note for advanced users: The equals sign used here for copy initialization is part of the initialization syntax, and is not considered a use of the assignment operator that gets invoked when doing copy assignment)"

What does that mean? Is it saying that the '=' operator when used for initializing is not the same when used in copy assignment?

Also, it states, "Direct initialization can perform better than copy initialization for some data types, and comes with some other benefits once we start talking about classes. It also helps differentiate initialization from assignment. Consequently, we recommend using direct initialization over copy initialization."

Can someone please help clearing things up for me and explaining it simpler terms? Thanks

Comment: `=` symbol when used for initialization does not mean `=` operator invocation at all. Therefore It is a good idea to never use copy initialization syntax.

Comment: "Is it saying that the '=' operator when used for initializing is not the same when used in copy assignment?" - yes. Your C++ textbook should cover this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

For primitive types, copy initialization is the exact same as direct initialization. For more complex types with constructors, copy initialization is the same as calling the copy constructor with the value after the `=`, unless that copy constructor is marked `explicit`.

A little demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar
{
    int x;
    bar() : x(30) {}
};

struct foo
{
    int x;
    foo() : x(42) { std::cout << "Default constructor\n"; }
    foo(const foo &other) : x(other.x) { std::cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    foo(const int &y) : x(y) { std::cout << "Copy/conversion constructor with int\n"; }
    explicit foo(const bar &y) : x(y.x) { std::cout << "Copy/conversion constructor with bar\n"; }
    foo& operator=(const foo &other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment operator\n";
        x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a; //calls default constructor
    foo w; //calls default constructor
    w = a; //then the assignment operator
    foo b = a; //calls copy constructor, not copy assignment operator, different from previous
    foo c(a); //also calls copy constructor, same as previous
    foo d = 10; //same as foo d(10), constructor that takes an int can be used for conversions
    bar h;
    foo j(h); //calls copy/conversion constructor that takes a bar,
              //the contructor can also be used for explicit conversions
    //foo k = h; //error because of implicit conversion when constructor is marked explicit
    return 0;
}
```

As shown in the demo, the `=` in an initialization is not the same as the `=` in an assignment. I'm not sure what they mean in the part about performance since copy initialization is usually the same as direct initialization and calls the same constructor.

Comment: Thanks that explains things a lot better!